# Serialize nullalbe value with ZonedDateTimeSerializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I have a nullable ZonedDateTime value that should be serialized to JSON using com.fasterxml.jackson.

I am currently doing it like so:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = ElasticSearchConstants.ZONED_DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
@JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = ZonedDateTimeDeserializerFromIsoText.class)
private ZonedDateTime myVariable;
```

What I would expect to happen if `myVariable == null` is this:

```
{
    "myVariable": null
}
```

What I get is:

```
{}
```

This seems about right since the ZonedDateTimeSerializer expects a non-null input. Is there a way to get it to work with null values? If not, is there another serializer that I could use for this that does? Or do I have to write my own serializer?

Comment: Try adding `@JsonInclude` - the default option of `ALWAYS` should include the property when null.

Comment: Can you show ZonedDateTimeDeserializerFromIsoText

Comment: @AndrewS Do you want to put this into an answer so I can accept it? (Additional context for anyone stumbling over this in the future: There was a class-wide `@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)`).